# ESX 5.5 and Virtual Ubuntu, no internet connection

Tags: networking, esx, e1000

I have a hpe blade system c3000 with 8 blades.

On a number of blades, right now 4, I run ESXi version 5.5

I can easily create virtual Windows Server / Windows 10 machines and get proper access to the Internet and the other network.

But this does not work with Ubuntu.

Have tried both VMXNET3 and E1000 as a network adapter in ESX, but the problem remains.

Has installed VmWare tools on the virtual computer running VMXNET3 without success.

**Ubuntu with E1000 network adapter**

Se images:

[cat /etc/networking/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdaI5.png), 
 [ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3fN1.png), 
  [ping results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z9vE.png)

**Ubuntu with VMXNET3 network adapter**

See images:

[cat /etc/networking/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmbIt.png), 
[ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay1xO.png), 
[ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHw8b.png)

This problem with the network are the same on other linux dist, like Debian. (Debian fails during the installation, because no connection to the internet is OK)

No firewall active.

```
ufw status = inactive
```

So my questions are.

What should I use? E1000 or VMXNET3?

How do I get this is working.

(Ubuntu Server 14.04 och Ubuntu Server 18.04 Same results)

Virtual Switch: 
[Switch image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXTWf.png) , 
[Switch image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YECV1.png)

Comment: You should check your virtual switch, did you bind it to a physical interface, are you using the same virtual switch than Windows machine ?

Comment: Yes its the same virtual Switch.

Update my post with an image of the switch overview

Comment: Are you able to ping the vswitch IP from your Ubuntu (ping 192.168.1.120)? Where is your DHCP server, outside of your VMware farm?

Comment: I can ping 192.168.1.120 without any problems.

My DHCP server is located in my Unifi USG Router  (192.168.1.1)


[Router Unifi USG (192.168.1.1)] --> [Unifi Switch] --> [Switch on the C3000] --> [VMWare Switch] --> [Virtual machines, like Ubuntu and Windows server]  (Windows Servers works great)

Answer (score 1):

Which Switch Module are you using on the c3000?

I would check there to see if the MAC Address from the Ubuntu VM is even making it to the Physical Switch/Virtual Connect in the chassis.

If it is, then the problem is likely Layer 3, or the uplinks, or outside the chassis.
If the MAC is not showing up in the Switch Module, then it's something on the VMware to VM side of things.